# Why does higher level mathematics more often than not use Greek lettering?

Tags: soft-question, notation

In high school, at least from what I've seen, mathematics courses never use Greek lettering in their description of concepts, with the notable exceptions of $\Sigma$ for summations, $\Delta$ for changes over time, $\pi$ as $3.14159\ldots$, $\tau$ in physics courses, and $\theta$ for basic sines, cosines, and tangents. This behavior is mirrored in typical college placement exams, such as the SAT or AP exams, which also do not typically use any Greek lettering.

Yet, when students enter college, classes and instructors do use Greek lettering, and use it without preamble; they assume students are familiar with such notation. Yet, typical freshman are not familiar with Greek lettering, and are not sure how to draw, pronounce, or think in terms of, such letters.

Is there a specific reason Greek lettering is deferred to the high school $\to$ university transition, and, more generally, for Greek lettering in the first place?

Comment: Do you know any terms from (biology, physics, chemistry, literature, foreign language, music theory, etc) before they are defined?!? There's no reason to fear the unknown Greek letters. You'll learn how to pronounce them, then what they mean in various contexts.

Comment: Mostly, I suppose, to classify a quantity as a "parameter", rather than a constant or a variable (or vice versa). So, anything considered a variable, e.g., uses roman forms and anything that is a parameter uses greek forms.

Comment: @TheChaz: No. But instructors take time to define such terms. They do not take the time to define greek lettering. They just use it and assume everyone's on the bandwagon.

Comment: @David: I've never seen that convention used/stated. I've seen some books which make anything greek-lettered a function rather than a variable. I've seen books that do the reverse. I've seen books that use both indiscriminately. But at the end of the day it just means students are forced to learn an entire new alphabet in addition to mathematics.

Comment: See this answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/why-do-mathematicians-use-single-letter-variables/24246#24246

Comment: I would expect anyone who is able to grasp the trig identities to be able to learn 24 letters...

Comment: Surely the professor says the word "alpha" as he writes $\alpha$ on the board. What else can be done? Even if you devoted an entire day to the Greek alphabet, would it really sink in after such a short time? It's simply one of those things that becomes natural after a time.

Comment: @TheChaz: If only such a thing could be enforced. The only letter I associate with anything is k with my chemistry courses, because they liked to replace any constant with k and expect you to figure it out :)

Comment: One big problem is that we only have 26 letters in our alphabet.  We often use other alphabets to distinguish types of variables - so we'll write $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ in calculus to represent small increments in the domain and range of a function, but use $x$ when discussing an element in the range.  This is essentially visual typing.

Comment: @t.b.: I'm not saying that it's impossible to learn. I'm not saying that it's unreasonble to learn. I'm merely saying it's strange that it's not touched on at all until someone enters "academia". I'm asking if there is a basis for that or not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I have yet to see an equation that requires more than 26 variables. Then again, I'm not studying to become a mathematician.

Comment: This leads to the question: When Greek students learn calculus, do they learn the $e-d$ definition of continuity, or is it still $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I don't know how that would affect other languages. But I would expect that it would be defined when the concepts were defined. I never saw δ or ϵ in high school.

Comment: @Austin: Maybe you had better teachers than I did. I had a hard enough time understanding what they were talking about when they were not speaking about this sort of thing at all. Maybe that just means I was unlucky with instructors, but this difficulty is a problem I've noticed in a far greater population than myself.

Comment: @BillyONeal It's true, few equations need 26 variable, but, in context, a lot of variables have specific meanings.  For example, we rarely use $n$ to be a function, and $i$ and $j$ are often "indexes."  If I'm reading a paper with lots of different types of objects (sets, functions, variables, constants, ...) I want a way of knowing what type of object the letter represents.  And mathematics is far more than just equations. Some books will use different fonts for different types - for example $\mathcal{R}$ versus $\mathbb{R}$ versus $R$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Students are exposed to differing fonts and such in  early grade school, when number classes (E.g. reals, integers, etc.) are taught. More to the point, a reason to introduction of the differing notation is brought in and explained as part of teaching the notation. I can't say the same for the greek.

Comment: Note, you've skewed far from your original, essentially neutral question, "why?" to complaining about your misfortune at nobody preparing you or helping you.  That's not productive.  The "why" is a complex mix of reasons, from simplicity, to convention, to history (Greek was a common part of classical education into the 20th century). The "why me" is another matter entirely.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I apologize if it's coming off that way -- that was not my intent at all. I'm not at all bitter or angry about this -- though looking back on this it looks like it may be taken that way. Oops. Let me see if I can fix that...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Okay, rewritten. Is that better?

Comment: @BillyONeal: `I have yet to see an equation requiring more than 26 variables;` somewhat true. And you could, in principle, simply always use the next available letter and not worry unless you actually run out. Your computer would probably have no trouble doing that. In *practice* however, it would be very hard to actually use, because you would have no visual clues as to what each term might be.

Comment: Because only set theorists know the Hebrew alphabet!

Comment: On a more serious note, the reason it happens at the university level is that high school teachers tend to obsess over the difficulty that these little notational details could cause their students, while college professors expect their students to be able to digest ideas presented with any reasonable form of notation. This is related to the fact that high school teachers teach the same subjects, often from the same textbook, year after year and do not read research artciles that requires the ability to transition between different notations, while the opposite is generally true of professors.

Comment: "Turns out, it's extremely hard to understand what an equation is telling you when you can't even say the equation in your head."  That's interesting.  I have no problem following equations even if I don't know how to say the letters out loud.  Is this a visual learner vs verbal learner thing?

Comment: There are currently 3 votes to close (as nonconstructive). However, I think the question in its current form is fine - it can admit direct answers such as "this change is not deferred to university", "the change is gradual", or "this change is deferred to university, because of \_\_\_", and answers (such as Thomas Andrews') can also address the historical reasons for using Greek letters in otherwise-non-Greek mathematical writing. So I don't see a reason to close or CW, but I am of course open to hearing arguments for either.

Comment: "Let $\epsilon \to 0$. There goes the neighborhood!" - this is funny, and accessible, since epsilon (a.) *always means the same thing!*

Comment: I have to wonder why we *don't* use Hebrew more often and Cyrillic ever... not that I want to have to learn the Cyrillic alphabet, mind you!

Comment: If you care about the symbols used you are wrong in that lecture. It's important that symbols are pronouncable, though, and conventions are a nice thing, too, even though they effectively block symbols. Greek alphabet is a gracious choice; just look it up om Mamma Wiki. They could use *any* TeX symbol, you know?

Comment: A little off-topic, but... there is a polynomial formula for the primes that uses exactly 26 variables (Jones, J., Sato, D., Wada, H. and Wiens, D. (1976). Diophantine representation
of the set of prime numbers. _American Mathematical Monthly_, 83,
449-464.)

Comment: In trigonometry, Greek letters usually denote quantities related to angles (angle $\alpha$, angular velocity $\omega$) while Roman letters usually denote quantities related to lengths (side $a$, linear velocity $v$).

Comment: @HarryAltman: What about the Tate-Shafarevich group, which is denoted by Sha (Ш)?

Comment: I did not know about that, thank you!

Comment: I downvoted this question because the asker gave no thought to the unspoken assumption that everyone has to guess that this question is about (at most) the US only. From the mathematical point of view, the proper question is why *Latin* letters are used in mathematics at all.

Comment: @Phira: Nobody ever said that you can only ask mathematics questions which relate to everyone on the face of the earth. I would assume that if your native language differed that you would use different characters in typical mathematics. More to the point though, this is an English speaking website and therefore asking questions that apply to English speaking countries is not unreasonable. That's more than the US -- that includes Britain, Australia, and most of India as well. Moreover, the two other most common languages (French, Spanish) use the same Latin glyphs English uses.

Comment: @Phira: In other words, if you think that's a problem, go ask your own question. I don't see how I could have incorporated your concern into this question, and therefore I don't see why you think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: Why not answer-ify that?

Comment: @BillyONeal Most of your question is about the US education system, and not about mathematics (and not about English speaking countries, either). It is not hard to state at the beginning that it is a question about the US education system, you are just not willing to do so, which is your prerogative and earns you my downvote. Your list of most common languages is quite interesting.

Comment: @Phira: Okay, so you want everything everywhere that might be US oriented, even when that content is on a site hosted in the United States and whose users are mostly US native or native to other English speaking countries, to carry a label saying that it's language specific? That's unreasonable. Fine, if you're going to be that way, downvote away. In the mean time, I'll start up my counter proposal to get every site hosted in Spain and whose users speak Spanish to indicate on all their content that it's Spain centric (and repeat this for every country/language combination).

Comment: @BillyONeal This site is not "everything everywhere", it is the FAQ that counts, not the host, and US-specific is not language-specific. The problem is that your assumptions are wrong. Look at http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F and http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA to get the Russian and Hebrew wikipedia definitions of a continuous function. The mathematical part of your question is illposed as a US-centric question, the other part is probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe greek letters are now playing the role of the slide rule (you're too young to need them in High School, you are assumed to already know them first year of college)...

I honestly think that if the use of different letters made "things [you] considered easy difficult", then you didn't know them well enough (though you thought you did). I find that students who get confused in calculus when the function is not called $f$ but is called something else don't really understand what is going on, and if the same sort of thing happened to you with algebra when switching from $a$, $b$, $c$, to $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, then there was a gap in your understanding that went beyond not knowing the greek alphabet.

Now, there are only so many letters around; and in order to try to give some order to the use of letters, certain letters tend to be used for specific purposes. We generally use $a$, $b$, $c$, etc for algebra constants; we tend to use $f$, $g$, $h$ for functions; $i$, $j$, $k$ for indices (and $i$ gets reserved for the imaginary unit in some contexts); $m$ and $n$ usually denote integers. Lower case $o$ is too easy to confuse with $0$; $t$, $u$, $v$, $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$ are often used for variables; etc. There are only so many letters to go around, and soon you start needing new letters to make things easier. The use of greek letters is not designed to confuse, it's designed to *clarify*, by leaving other letters to their "standard" uses.

(Of course, you could simply have looked up the Greek alphabet, or requested the instructor to help you with it; I remember when I took Algebraic Number Theory in grad school, the professor distributed on the first day a sheet with the handwritten fraktur alphabet so we would know that $\frak{P}$ was a capital $P$, etc.)

Comment: +1, okay this is reasonable. Perhaps I should have clarified what I meant by "difficult". I'm thinking more in terms of mechanical errors (e.g. misplaced something because a letter was confused) than conceptual problems. (e.g. "t" has this problem in that it's often confused with tau or + when hand written)

Comment: @Billy: That kind of issue shows up with regular letters too! I've seen too many students confuse `t` with `+`, as you mention, or confuse `x` with `y` because they are written too similarly (not to mention $a$ with $0$). I forced myself, when I got to college, to stop writing `x` and `y` and to start writing $x$ and $y$ instead, precisely to avoid confusion. Now it comes naturally.

Comment: Yea; I started to strike the vertical line of my q for similar reasons. Actually, visual ambiguities are a big reason to use (e.g.) greek letters alongside the roman. As you'll notice, nobody uses kappa and omicron but rather those more discernible. Sadly though, small omega is often used near w, which drives me crazy.

Comment: It's a shame you CW'd this. :( Accepted.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I CW'd it because I feel the entire question should be CW's. I flagged it for moderator attention, but clearly they disagreed.

Answer (score 16):

Hugh Montgomery once did some thinking-out-loud about the possibility of writing a paper where, whenever he needed a new symbol, he would just take the first letter of the alphabet he hadn't already used. The title would be, On the Riemann $a$-function, and the paper would begin, Let $a(b)=\sum_{c=1}^{\infty}c^{-b}$.... He concluded that the paper would be unreadable.

The point is that mathematicians have adopted conventions. The convention adopted may not make sense, or may not make any more sense than any of the possible alternative conventions, but once it is adopted it is of enormous value in communication, which is what mathematics is about. Once you have been inducted into the conventions, you can instantly grasp $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$ because you have so many associations with it, whereas it takes a great effort to understand $a(b)=\sum_{c=1}^{\infty}c^{-b}$.

Comment: Considering that the OP is a programmer, it might be noteworthy that conventions are not only essential to understanding mathematics. Nobody *forces* you to call your methods `getX`, `setX` or `isX` and your look counters `i` and `j`, after all.

Comment: @Raphael: Funny you should mention that. I don't think most such rigid conventions make sense in programmer land either :P But I can see your point +1.

Comment: @BillyONeal You may be interested in this [analysis of the topic by Terence Tao](https://profiles.google.com/114134834346472219368/buzz/1N1eaNU1mW6). The essence is that the differing notation is actually there to help you. Whether they mean to or not, the characters we use begin to become attributed with implicit meanings, and while we could use different letters than we were accustomed to it would actually hurt our understanding rather than help it.

Answer (score 6):

Historically, part of a classical education used to be learning Ancient Greek and Latin, so most college students and above were expected to know the Greek alphabet.

A pure example of this history is the naming of college fraternities with Greek letters.

Today, very few English-speakers learn Greek, so there might be a value to having instructors at least present to students a list of the Greek alphabet, with pronunciations, to make acclimation easier.

Typically, the first Greek letter we learn is $\pi$, followed by $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in calculus.  Maybe $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$.  But we certainly don't have a systematic intro. I know I couldn't tell you the entire Greek alphabet in order, and still forget the names of some of them, particularly $\xi$ for some reason.  (Note - we don't tend to use the Greek letters that look like their Roman alternates, precisely because we are using the change in alphabet to represent types, and so using those letters would hardly be helpful.)

Comment: +1. I didn't see ϵ until late calc 2 -- in high school $x_0$ was used instead. δ wasn't used until calc 3. Completely forgot about pi, delta, and sigma though -- I've fixed those in my question.

Comment: I suspect a lot of people learn $\Sigma$ without really knowing it is a letter in another alphabet.  There are plenty of math symbols, like $\exists$ and $\forall$, that are not letters.

Comment: @Billy I don't think anyone would use $x_0$ in place of $\epsilon$. My guess is that $x_0$ would've been the point to which $x$ approached (i.e., $x \to x_0$).

Comment: @Srivatsan: Hmm.. maybe it was delta X. E.g. $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$

Comment: There may be an even older reason. Back in the day when you printed with a press, you would have lead glyphs for roman letters, and maybe for greek, but which else? So it would only be natural to choose (new) symbols you could actually print.

Comment: @Raphael: Printers had those letters because most educated people were taught Greek, so I think you have the time frames wrong.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_education_movement

Comment: Agreed, shouldn't have written "older". Don't care wether it was chicken or egg; I was just thinking that maybe being able to actually print stuff was a good motivator to use these symbols rather than make up others.