# Is it correct to define variables and functions that are more than one character?

Tags: education, convention

Most of the time (at least at my high school student level), we are using variables such as *a*, *b* or $\theta$, and functions such as *f, g* etc...

But would it be possible to use multiple characters ? For example to use *triple(x) = 3x* instead of *f(x) = 2x* ?
In my opinion it would enable some things to be much more clear in many situations, here is another example :
$$area = width \times height$$
Instead of $a = w \times h$, where you would need to go back in the text to find wha a, w and h are for.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/why-do-mathematicians-use-single-letter-variables

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible, and it is done. Some examples: $\log x$, $\sin x$ and the trigonometric functions, $\text{div}$ (divergence operator), $\text{grad}$ (gradient, also $\nabla$), $\det A$ (determinant).

The use of a single character is a matter of economy. You can use whatever notation you like, as long as you explain it if it is not standard.

Comment: I did thought to *log, sin etc...* functions, but I thought that maybe it was possible only with those sort of *"standard"* functions... (by standard I mean the ones that you don't write yourself). Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is done all the time in computing.  It is a major help when reading someone else's program.
We also use subscripts - rather than ($x,y,z$), we might write $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$; then refer to any one of them as $x_i$

Comment: Yeah, I'm developing things and that's exactly why I wondered if it was possible in maths  :)